# I18n error message of restrict_dependent_destroy: interpolated %{record} is downcase, which is grammatically incorrect in German

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I just noticed, that the I18n of `activerecord.messages.restrict_dependent_destroy` interpolates the `%{record}` key while making it **downcase**:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    messages:
      restrict_dependent_destroy:
        one: Cannot delete record because a dependent %{record} exists
```

Becomes:

```
Cannot delete record because a dependent users exists
```

For english, this is fine, but for German, nouns must start uppercase:

```
Kann Datensatz nicht löschen, weil abhängige benutzer existieren # Must be "Benutzer"!
```

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: I think the only possible way is by monkeypatching [I18n.interpolate_hash](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/3269c01edf3bb9537602bf0467a6bab38b3d9ba6/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb#L22) to eval the placeholder so that you can do `Kann Datensatz nicht löschen, weil abhängige #{record.capitalize} existieren`. There is an older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642901/how-to-change-case-of-interpolated-variables-in-rails-locale-file) that may be a duplicate but I'm not sure its relevant for the latest versions of rails.

Comment: Another possible solution is by overriding [ActiveModel::Naming#model_name](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-i-model_name) in your models with something like `I18n.locale == :de ? super.capitalize : super`. But that might just create new problems as its not context aware.

Answer (score 2):

The problem does not lie in your translation dictionaries.Thats why changing it to uppercase in your dictionaries did not work.

Below are the code snippets from the `activerecord-5.1.6` handler function for both has_one and has_many associations for your specific error, meaning: `restrict_dependent_destroy`.

**has_one:**

```
  def handle_dependency
    case options[:dependent]
    when :restrict_with_exception
      raise ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError.new(reflection.name) if load_target

    when :restrict_with_error
      if load_target
        record = owner.class.human_attribute_name(reflection.name).downcase
        owner.errors.add(:base, :'restrict_dependent_destroy.has_one', record: record)
        throw(:abort)
      end

    else
      delete
    end
  end
```

**has_many:**

```
def handle_dependency
    case options[:dependent]
    when :restrict_with_exception
      raise ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError.new(reflection.name) unless empty?

    when :restrict_with_error
      unless empty?
        record = owner.class.human_attribute_name(reflection.name).downcase
        owner.errors.add(:base, :'restrict_dependent_destroy.has_many', record: record)
        throw(:abort)
      end

    when :destroy
      # No point in executing the counter update since we're going to destroy the parent anyway
      load_target.each { |t| t.destroyed_by_association = reflection }
      destroy_all
    else
      delete_all
    end
  end
```

In both cases as you can see the "record" is obtained through the following line:

```
record = owner.class.human_attribute_name(reflection.name).downcase
```

You stated that this is your problem.

Override the specific functions I just showed in the snippets and remove the `.downcase` call from the end of both of them and its bound to work.

If you do not know how to override gem module methods refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/580504/7945232) question

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to change the locale of User:

```
# config/locales/de.yml
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: "Benutzer"
```

By doing so, your translation should pickup the new translation with upercase in the code above. Don't forget to restart your rails server.

Comment: I think the correct key would be `de.activerecord.models.user.one`. This is exactly the way I'm having it in my app, and I expected it to work. But it doesn't. Hence this question.